# Can a 1st differential equation have two different solutions?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, line-integrals

I am given the following differential equation:
$$x^2y'-y^2=1$$ where $y(1)=0$
and asked solve it:

---

lets divide the DE by $x^2$, $$y'-\frac{1}{x^2}\cdot y^2=\frac{1}{x^2}, x\ne0$$

Now lets find the find the integrating factor (IF):

$$e^{\int( -\frac{1}{x^2})dx}= e^{\frac{1}{x}}$$

Now lets multiply the DE by IF we get :
$$(y^2\cdot e^{\frac{1}{x}})'=\frac{1}{x^2}\cdot e^{\frac{1}{x}}$$
hence
$$y^2\cdot e^\frac{1}{x}= e^{\frac{1}{x}}+c$$
we know that  $y(1)=0$ and we have already established that $x\ne 0$
we then get that $c=-1$ and hence the solution to the differential equation becomes:
$y(x)= \pm \sqrt{1-\frac{1}{e^{\frac{1}{x}}}}$

**Here is another problem** though, i dont know when to choose the positive square root or the negative one for DEs. Is there any way to know what to choose?

Anyhow the books solution (i have the worked solution right in front of me here) says that:
$$y(x)=tan(1-\frac{1}{x}), x>\frac{2}{2+\pi}$$

I fail to see what went wrong with my solution? and **WHY** is it wrong?

Comment: How did you get this integrating factor? Note that this isn't a first-order linear ODE.

Comment: You have a non-linear ode - so integrating factor is out at the stage you do it.

Comment: You have a separable equation right off the bat..

Comment: If it is a linear differential equation, then yes only one unique solution. Otherwise, take a look for the existence/uniqueness theorem for first order DEs.

Comment: Guys thank you a lot for notifying me about that, so whenever there is a power higher than 1 then the IF can no longer be applicable am i correct on this one?

Comment: It is even more stricter than that - If you do not have a linear function then you cannot have an IF.

Comment: @Chinny84 Then you *aren't guaranteed* to have an IF. But many differential equations will have such an IF, of course, finding them is a matter of mostly magic.

Comment: Make sure you understand what the integrating factor is actually doing, and why it solves the DE. If you can understand the reverse product rule going on here, then the restrictions become clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write $(y^2 e^{\frac{1}{x}})'$ at one time, but notice that
$$\frac{d}{dx} y^2 e^{\frac{1}{x}} = 2y y' e^{\frac{1}{x}} + y^2 e^{\frac{1}{x}} \frac{-1}{x^2}.$$
Do you see that $2y y'$ term there? That does not appear in your differential equation. In particular, you do not have a linear differential equation, so this technique won't work towards a solution.

---

It's worth mentioning that many of your questions would clear up by your checking the solution. Suppose that you *did* have two candidate solutions that looked like $\pm g(x)$. How can you determine which one (or if both) work? Plug them back into the differential equation and check!

This would reveal to you that your proposed solutions do not actually solve the differential equation as well.

Comment: do you mean the i should find g'(x) and compare it against the DE?

Comment: Just as with solving something like $x + 2 = 5$, you can check a solution (say, $3$) by plugging and and verifying (so $3 + 2 = 5$ indeed). If you want to verify a solution to a differential equation, plug in your solution and verify.